# How do I "Add In" four user forms into 2013 PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, userform

I have four UserForms written in VBA, 2013 PowerPoint presentation created in Windows 10. The UserForms help me create a presentation. To use it in creating other presentations without opening the presentation where the original VBA scripts are found, I exported each of the form to an external file. Then for each new presentation, I import the exported UserForms.

What are some of the ways I can “add in” the four user forms into the PowerPoint application so that I don’t have to import them every time I create a new presentation?

Comment: have you done research?

Comment: http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00031_Create_an_ADD-IN_with_TOOLBARS_that_run_macros.htm

Answer (score 0):

Start by following the link Tim provided.  Create an addin from your presentation with the forms.  Ignore the stuff about toolbars; you won't need them for this.

Then have a look at this:

http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00403_Call_a_macro_in_another_presentation_and_pass_it_parameters.htm

You can call subroutines (ie macros) in other presentations OR in add-ins, so if your add-in is installed, you can call its public routines from code in other presentations.

OR

You might want to put the entire thing into the add-in, include toolbar or RibbonX UI and have the code in the add-in act on the ActivePresentation.  That way you wouldn't need any code at all in your actual presentations.